# Mysteriously fails to compile when I comment a line

Tags: macros, errors, listings

I set up a [github repo](https://github.com/bacey/texproblem) with a not-so minimal working environment (sorry for that).

As the README at github says, uncommenting the following stupid line solves the problem and makes the `diplomadolgozat.tex` file compilable.

```
%\begin{figure}[h]\end{figure}
```

There are other lines which when deleted make the compiler happy, but it's all unpredictable. Until now everything was fine, but this error made my whole writing process unstable: I no longer know when will it break again and when it breaks, why.

If you have some time for it, clone the github repo, see it for yourself.

Comment: I think most people would be quite reluctant to compile such a complex document downloaded off the internet. May I suggest you try to boil it down to a smaller example, or at least post the log file of your failed compile run?

Comment: See these instructions on how to produce a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). It is not as hard as you could be thinking, and there is a high possibility that you will find the problem in the process.

Comment: As the other comments say, in the current form this question is 'too localized' as it is completely tied to a single document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nearly any modification which change page breaks will make the error go away, so it seems to me that there is a problem if a page break occurs inside a listing, and there is a pending floating environment. (I was able to strip down your document to a far smaller example document which still shows the error, see below.)

But the main reason for the trouble seems to be the version 1.5b of `magyar.ldf` inside your document folder. When using the version v1.4j provided by TeXlive 2011 instead, the error will go away, too, and I was not able to get the error back by changing content of the document.

So it seems that the version 1.5b of magyar.ldf is having at least one bug. Here is an example document still showing the error when using v1.5b of magyar.ldf:

```
\begin{filecontents}{compiler.clj}
;;{antIfStar}
(defn ant-if* [kond true-branch false-branch]
  {:pre [(every? node? [kond true-branch false-branch]) 
  (binary-node? kond)]
   :post [(node? %)]}
  (let [[t-node f-node] (mark-branches true-branch 
    false-branch)
        ztrue (to-ztree t-node)
        zkond (to-ztree kond)]
    (->> f-node
         (insert-at-the-bottom ztrue ,,,)
         (insert-under-a-jump-to-true-label zkond ,,,))))
;;{end}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\def\magyarOptions{defaults=hu-min}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{2.5cm}{2cm}{1.5cm}{1.5cm}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\linespread{1.3}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
(ant-if (sense :ahead :foe)  ; feltétel
        (turn :left)         ; igaz ág
        (turn :right))       ; hamis ág
\end{verbatim}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[bb=0 0 227 345,scale=0.85]{a.png}
  \caption{\texttt{(turn :right)}}
  \label{antSenseAFoe}
\end{figure}

A \verb|Sense Ahead| csúcsnak két \verb|"jump" UnaryNode| gyermeke van. Ha a \verb|Sense Ahead| feltétele igaz, tehát ha előttem egy ellenséges hangya áll, akkor a baloldali \verb|"jump" :next| értelmében a következő utasításon kell folytatnom, ami a [T1] címkével jelölt \emph{Turn Left}. Ha a feltétel nem igaz, tehát ha nincs előttem ellenség, akkor jobboldali \verb|"jump" F1| -- aminek a \verb|:target| mezőjében F1 szerepel -- az [F1] címkéjű \emph{Turn Right} utasításra irányít.

A \verb|Sense Ahead| csúcsnak két \verb|"jump" UnaryNode| gyermeke van. Ha a \verb|Sense Ahead| feltétele igaz, tehát ha előttem egy ellenséges hangya áll, akkor a baloldali \verb|"jump" :next| értelmében a következő utasításon kell folytatnom, ami a [T1] címkével jelölt \emph{Turn Left}. Ha a feltétel nem igaz, tehát ha nincs előttem ellenség, akkor jobboldali \verb|"jump" F1| -- aminek a \verb|:target| mezőjében F1 szerepel -- az [F1] címkéjű \emph{Turn Right} utasításra irányít.

A \verb|Sense Ahead| csúcsnak két \verb|"jump" UnaryNode| gyermeke van. Ha a \verb|Sense Ahead| feltétele igaz, tehát ha előttem egy ellenséges hangya áll, akkor a baloldali \verb|"jump" :next| értelmében a következő utasításon kell folytatnom, ami a [T1] címkével jelölt \emph{Turn Left}. Ha a feltétel nem igaz, tehát ha nincs előttem ellenség, akkor jobboldali \verb|"jump" F1| -- aminek a \verb|:target| mezőjében F1 szerepel -- az [F1] címkéjű \emph{Turn Right} utasításra irányít.

A \verb|Sense Ahead| csúcsnak két \verb|"jump" UnaryNode| gyermeke van. Ha a \verb|Sense Ahead| feltétele igaz, tehát ha előttem egy ellenséges hangya áll, akkor a baloldali \verb|"jump" :next| értelmében a következő utasításon kell folytatnom, ami a [T1] címkével jelölt \emph{Turn Left}. Ha a feltétel nem igaz, tehát ha nincs előttem ellenség, akkor jobboldali \verb|"jump" F1| -- aminek a \verb|:target| mezőjében F1 szerepel -- az [F1] címkéjű \emph{Turn Right} utasításra irányít.

Az \verb|ant-if| csak annyit csinál, hogy

\lstinputlisting[linerange=antIfStar-end]{compiler.clj}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I exchanged v1.5b to v1.4j as you suggested, but it doesn't define the \mond command. As I'm already past the deadline (with 2 weeks) to submit my diploma thesis, I don't have the time today to learn the latex macro programming (for being able to implement \mond), therefore I now live with v1.5b and hope that it won't let me down. But thanks again your valuable contribution!

Answer (score 5):

Jake and Andrey, you are totally right.

After getting some sleep and a somehow cleaner head, I tried to minify my master document. Commenting out the `\def\magyarOptions{defaults=hu-min}` line solved the problem.

I hope that was the real problem, and I hope I solved it permanently. If not, I just continue minifying it until I arrive to a MWE.